# Standard deviation - a general confusion.

Tags: statistics

I am confused by this question:

> A casino knows that people play the slot machines in hopes of hitting the jackpot, but the most of them lose their dollar. Suppose a certain machine pays out an average of 0.92, with a standard deviation of 120.

The question then is: **If somebody plays five times, what is the standard deviation of the casino's profit?**

The right answer, supposedly, is to divide the std by $\sqrt5$. I can see how, over consecutive attempts, the deviance from the mean would get smaller, but I am rather confused by the logic of the whole question - would that then mean that over time the standard deviation gets to zero?  What does then the 120 even mean - standard deviation of *what*? I suppose I need to clear a general confusion, as I am not quite sure what is the right question to ask.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves a *random variable*...that is, a real-valued function defined on the space of outcomes. In this case, a person plays five times, a certain outcome happens, and a real number (the casino's profit) emerges.

A random variable has a *[mass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function)*, which gives the probability that the random variable will take a certain value. From this, we can define things such as the mean, the standard deviation, etc.

In this case, the random variable is a sum of five *independent identically distributed* random variables. The individual variables are the ones you have information on.

Comment: Thanks, I am beginning to understand. In real terms (in terms of this question), what does the number 120 mean? I understand the concept of standard deviation, but I am confused by this question in particular.

Comment: @DahnJahn Do you also understand the concept of expectation?

Comment: I understand the way the expected value of a random variable is computed, not sure what expectation means. Sorry to be asking questions in a field in which I have very little prior education, I hoped there'd be a simple answer inducing an aha! moment.

Comment: @DahnJahn Expectation and expected value are the same. So the *variance* of a random variable $X$ is the expectation of $(X-\mu)^2$, where $\mu$ is the mean (expected value) of $X$. In other words, how far are we likely to be from the mean? If we shoot at a target from 100 feet away vs. 200 feet away, in both cases, the spatial average of our shots may be in the center of the target, but we're likely to miss by more from 200 feet than we are from 100 feet.

Standard deviation is the square root of the variance.